# Odoo controller, create record into database

Tags: json, controller, odoo

What is the python code for getting the JSON data from the mobile app and create into one2many field in odoo12 module in database 0r later?

I have written this for simple fields but don't know the code for one2many fields

```py
@http.route('/create_shipment', type='json', auth="user")
def create_shipment(self, **kw):
    if request.jsonrequest:
        if kw['company_name']:
            print('rec', kw)
            request.env['shipment.shipper'].sudo().create({
                'company_name': kw['company_name'],
                'company_NTN': kw['company_NTN'],
                'company_industry': kw['company_industry'],
                'company_address_city': kw['company_address_city'],
                'company_Address_street_address': kw['company_address_street_address'],
                'login': kw['login'],
                'password': kw['password'],
                'confirmpass': kw['confirmpass'],
                # "contact_person_info" :
            })
            args = {'success': True, 'message': 'Success'}
    return args
```

Comment: Check the [x2many](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/models.py#L3541) values filling source code documentation.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.huihoo.com/odoo/developer/12.0/reference/orm.html#model-reference : here you'll get complete information.
This may help you:

> (0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created
> with the given values dictionary
>
> (1, ID, { values })    update the    linked record with id = ID (write
> *values* on it)
>
> (2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id =
> ID (calls unlink on ID,    that will delete the object completely, and
> the link to it as well)
>
> (3, ID)                cut the link to the linked record with id = ID
> (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete
> the target object itself)
>
> (4, ID)                link to existing    record with id = ID (adds a
> relationship)
>
> (5)                       unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked
> records)
>
> (6, 0, [IDs])      replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then
> (4,ID) for each    ID in the list of IDs)

In your case you need to use (0, 0, { values    })

Comment: Is this a quote from the docs or what? If yes, please modify the link to pint exactly in the quoted excerpt